# on Javafx, Is there any way to draw a regular polygon without knowing the coordinates of all points(but merely knowing the number of sides?)

Tags: java, javafx, polygon

So for example, to draw a regular dodecagon on Javafx, you have to know all the coordinates of 12 points. But I was wondering if there's any way to draw it without knowing the coordinates of the points(but merely knowing that there are 12 sides for that polygon) so that if the user types '6', then it draws a regular hexagon and if the user types '12', it draws a regular dodecagon.

Comment: You need to use math to calculate the points. Then you can use them to draw a polygon.

Answer (score 5):

No, it's impossible to draw a polygon without knowing the the coordinates of the corners. How would such a object be rendered without the rendering engine knowing the coordinates of the vertices it needs to render?

You can of course calculate the coordinates of the points of a regular polygon given a center point, the distance of the corners from the center and the angle of one of the corners from the center point by convertion polar coordinates to cartesian coordinates:

```
private static void setPolygonSides(Polygon polygon, double centerX, double centerY, double radius, int sides) {
    polygon.getPoints().clear();
    final double angleStep = Math.PI * 2 / sides;
    double angle = 0; // assumes one point is located directly beneat the center point
    for (int i = 0; i < sides; i++, angle += angleStep) {
        polygon.getPoints().addAll(
                Math.sin(angle) * radius + centerX, // x coordinate of the corner
                Math.cos(angle) * radius + centerY // y coordinate of the corner
        );
    }
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Spinner<Integer> spinner = new Spinner(3, Integer.MAX_VALUE, 3);

    Polygon polygon = new Polygon();
    setPolygonSides(polygon, 200, 200, 150, spinner.getValue());
    spinner.valueProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        setPolygonSides(polygon, 200, 200, 150, spinner.getValue());
    });

    StackPane stackPane = new StackPane(polygon);
    stackPane.setPrefSize(400, 400);
    HBox root = new HBox(spinner, stackPane);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```